# LC filter sizing 50Hz AC to good DC (RMS to DC)

Tags: ac, filter, rms, passive-networks

I'm using a LTC1966 for a RMS to DC converter. My capacitor is a 10 µF. When measuring with an oscilloscope, I have a small ripple which I want to remove.

My result from ADC to the program shows a ripple of ~8-9bits, and it is to much.

Input to the circuit is a 230V 50Hz source. I've tried to add an 1 µH inductor in series with no luck. Do I need a 0.1 µH?

Note of interest: the output of LTC has a high output impedance of 85kohm and my ADC acctually doesn't want anything higher than 10kohm, but somehow it works.

LTC1966: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/design-note/dn288f.pdf

10 µF cap: http://se.farnell.com/avx/taja106k006rnj/capacitor-tant-10uf-6-3v-10-1206/dp/197014?Ntt=197014

So, what's the easiest way to reduce my ripple to produce the perfect DC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With RMS to DC conversion you will get ripple because (using traditional methods) the waveform is squared mathematically, then averaged then the square root is taken. It's the averaging process that is the weak link in the process and I guess it will be on this chip despite it using a sigma delta approach. The spec sheets recommends this for ripple reduction: -

[image]

If you can't use op-amps and you don't want to live with a long latency, maybe doing something in code will work. There are some clever filters that can be implemented or maybe you can just look for max and min and take the average of those values? Another idea might be to synchronize to the incoming AC so that you always take a reading at a repeatable point and hence this should give you a stable point in the RMS output?

By the way you'd need a big inductor to get anywhere near what the op-amp circuits can do. 1H (not uH) and 10uF will give you a 2nd order cut-off of 50Hz and your ripple (100Hz) will still be hardly affected - you'd be looking for something like a 10Hz LPF and that would need 25H and 10uF - an op-amp is easier.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I saw that. If possible I would like to avoid Op amps!

Comment: btw.. I did not down vote

Comment: The output cap is all ready a 10uF

Comment: @Christian Oh that's odd - I thought you'd said 1uF!! OK I'll alter my answer but the upshot is with RMS to DC conversion that you get ripple for regular non-square waveforms. You could do an average in code?

Comment: If it were that easy I would have done it! ;)

Background info: The output signal from the RMS circuit goes to a Zigbee circuit who reads the value twice every second and sends to my cpu where I want the resolution of one value every sec. Can't make the zigbee sending values more frequently!